# Onedit setvalues does not copy code values, only user input is copied

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGns0DGQbjlEpxTbdy1T_-m2oh7eK8tM9xyDzGqahJo/edit?usp=sharing

So I have this code that I thankfully got of the internet but I can't seem to get it to copy the other values in column 'C' from a code I have that fills in empty cells, sheet provided for reference.

```
function ss1OnEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='source_sheet') return;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rGns0DGQbjlEpxTbdy1T_-m2oh7eK8tM9xyDzGqahJo").getSheetByName("target_sheet").getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()).setValue(e.value);
}
//You can run this function all you want it will not create more than one trigger.  But you must run it once to setup the first trigger.
function createSS1OnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var trgs=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<trgs.length;i++) {
    if(trgs[i].getHandlerFunction()=="ss1OnEdit") {
      return;
    }
  }
  if(!found) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("ss1OnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

This code only sets the values that have been entered manually by hand. I would really appreciate if we can have it set cell value from code input.

I have been reading about this for a bit and the getdisplayvalue() but nothing so far worked for me.

Thank you!

Comment: onEdit triggers only fire for user edits.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question is why the user input fires the trigger, but the `Range.setValues()` doesn't. If that is correct, then it works as written on the [simple trigger docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started): «*onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet*». So a user change will fire the trigger, but a script change won't.

Comment: The above code is currently serving a portion of the database. However I would like to make set value for code input also, as I have automated a lot of procedures hence the request. I appreciate your reply Jacques thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. My answer was related to the original question, if you really need an answer for that second question, I strongly advise you to open a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jacques, I have asked another question, I hope this time I have clarified the problem a bit more.Thank you for your time :)